# Django form to let, add a person and his dependants

Tags: python, django, oop

I am writing a website that will save family data in an area. I want to have a form that lets me add information about family head and his/her dependants. My models are as follows

```
class Person(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    sex  = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Date of Birth', blank=True)
    id_no = models.CharField(verbose_name='National ID Card No', max_length=20)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class FamilyHead(Person):
    father_name = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Father/Husband Name', max_length=100)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    birth_place = models.CharField(verbose_name='Birt Place', max_length=30, blank=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    house_address = models.TextField(max_length = 100)

class AdultDependant(Person):
    guardian = models.ForeignKey('FamilyHead')
    relatin_w_guardian = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = STATUS)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I want to create a form that lets me add a FamilyHead and his/her multiple dependants. How to do that with django?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, please (over)read the [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) documentation so that at least you know where's what.

Concerning your specific case, you need 2 form instances. One [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for FamilyHead and one [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for the AdultDependant form list.

It might look a little hard the first time you use such features from Django, but don't panic Django makes it actually pretty easy.